# Change Sharepoint Icon in a new ribbon

Tags: sharepoint, ribbon

'm trying to add a ribbon in my project server site and it's working but I'm currently looking for a way to change my icon

Here the code I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Id="d6e0a4c1-19a9-4846-92fb-d0593aa3bbfc.myAppNewFormAction"
                RegistrationType="List"
                RegistrationId="115"
                Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
                Sequence="10001"
                Title="New myApp Form">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <!-- 
      Update the UI definitions below with the controls and the command actions
      that you want to enable for the custom action.
      -->
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.New.Controls._children">
          <Button Id="Ribbon.Documents.New.myAppNewFormActionButton"
                  Alt="New myApp Form"
                  Sequence="100"
                  Command="Invoke_myAppNewFormActionButtonRequest"
                  LabelText="New myApp Form"
                  TemplateAlias="o1"
                  Image32by32="Mysite/Pwa/ImageFolders/myAppLogoBug-onwhite-32.png"
                  Image16by16="Mysite/Pwa/ImageFolders/myAppLogoBug-onwhite-16.png" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler Command="Invoke_myAppNewFormActionButtonRequest"
                          CommandAction="~appWebUrl/Pages/Default.aspx?Action=New&amp;Source={Source}&amp;ListURLDir={ListUrlDir}"/>
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension >
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

So on my project server; I created a list in which I stored my image but it's not working, the icon shows me an empty case

I also tried to convert my image in base 64 but the result is the same :/

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My test demo for your reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Id="cfe1a724-53ea-4a66-acda-7bc69c2fff1c.CustomRibbonImage"
                RegistrationType="List"
                RegistrationId="{$ListId:OOBDoc;}"
                Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
                Sequence="10001"
                Title="Invoke &apos;CustomRibbonImage&apos; action">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <!-- 
      Update the UI definitions below with the controls and the command actions
      that you want to enable for the custom action.
      -->
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.New.Controls._children">
          <Button Id="Ribbon.Documents.New.CustomRibbonImageButton"
                  Alt="Request CustomRibbonImage"
                  Sequence="100"
                  Command="Invoke_CustomRibbonImageButtonRequest"
                  LabelText="Request CustomRibbonImage"
                  TemplateAlias="o1"
                  Image32by32="~sitecollection/SiteAssets/test.png"
                  Image16by16="~sitecollection/SiteAssets/test.png" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler Command="Invoke_CustomRibbonImageButtonRequest"
                          CommandAction="~appWebUrl/Pages/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}&amp;SPListItemId={SelectedItemId}&amp;SPListId={SelectedListId}"/>
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension >
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

[image]